# Using mvn deploy via webdav: directory creation

Tags: deployment, maven, webdav

I managed to setup maven so it automatically uploads the latest snapshot of our software to our public maven repository. 
This works fine so far, there is only a minor shortcoming that I just can not handle:

When deploying a new Snapshot, say for example: 
`<version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>`
a directory named `1.2-SNAPSHOT` has to be present on our webserver's maven directory, otherwise maven will fail, stating:

`Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact ... from/to basex.mvn`
`(http://abc.de/webdav/): Access denied to: http://abc.de/webdav/1.2-SNAPSHOT/...`

As usually when starting a new snapshot this very directory is not yet present so I end up creating it manually.

Do you have any ideas on how to come around this and make maven create this folder?

Comment: Creating the directory works using FTP?

Comment: yes it does, sorry for not being precise enough.

Comment: Haha, no worries :) . You should add it as an answer: I'll vote it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that it is not a server side problem?
I deployed a some libraries using Webdav (over HTTPS) and first time (with directory creation) it worked.

The `Pom.xml` should contain a description of the distribution server.

```
<distributionManagement>
   <repository>
      <id>RepoId</id>
      <name>Name of the Maven repository</name>
      <url>dav:https://thewebdavurl/</url>
      <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
   </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

To enable directory creation, you might need to log on the server. To do this you need to add in the server part of the `setting.xml` the credentials for `RepoId` (see id of the repository in the pom).

```
<server>
   <id>RepoId</id>
   <username>login</username>
   <password>pass</password>
</server>
```

Comment: Sorry for not coming back to you earlier, using the OSX Finder I am able to create directories via dav. Sorry I can not provide you with more information, but it works via FTP now, so we decided to stick with FTP.

Comment: Is the DAV server defined in the settings.xml? See message edited.

Comment: I am sorry, I totally forgot to come back here earlier; it turned out to be working using FTP, and I guess our DAV implementation was to blame here, for whatever reason I do not remember. I still accpeted your answer (after over a year :))